# Python/Numpy: numpy.apply_along_axis passes wrong kwargs (one too many arguments)

Tags: python, numpy, arguments, typeerror, keyword-argument

I am trying to make simple simulator for Stochastic Differential Equations (SDEs) based on Ito processes. In doing so, I tried to make a 1D simulator as follows:

```
def sde_euler_1(t0: float, x0: float, T: float, M: int, a, b):
    t = np.zeros(shape=M+1)
    t[0] = t0
    x = np.zeros(shape=(M+1))
    x[0] = x0
    dt = T / M

    for j in range(M):
        t[j+1] = t[j] + dt
        dW = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1.0, size=1)
        x[j+1] = x[j] + a(t[j], x[j]) * dt + b(t[j], x[j]) * dW * np.sqrt(dt)

    return x
```

It works as expected. Where `a` and `b` are functions such as seen below in the `__main__`-function where they are specified in order to simulate a Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM).

However, there are many different ways of simulating SDEs, and often one wants to repeat the simulation N times in order to perform Monte Carlo Integration (Estimation). Hence, I tried to make a function, which takes uses `numpy.apply_along_axis` in order to this. It is defined as such

```
def mc_sim(t0: float, x0: float, T: float, M: int, N: int, a, b, sde_method, seed: int = 0):
    if seed > 0:
        np.random.seed(seed=seed)
    x = np.zeros(shape=(M+1, N))
    x = np.apply_along_axis(func1d=sde_method, axis=0, arr=x,
                            t0=t0, x0=x0, T=T, M=M, a=a, b=b)

    return x
```

My issue is that when I run the code below (the `__main__`-function) then I get the following error:

> TypeError: sde_euler_1() got multiple values for argument 't0'

It seems to me that I'ved passed exactly the 6 arguments used in my function but still I get the error. Here is my code contained in

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    def a(t, x):
        return 0.07 * x

    def b(t, x):
        return 0.2 * x

    t0 = 0.0
    x0 = 100
    T = 5.0
    N = 10
    M = 250
    seed = 1

    t = np.linspace(start=t0, stop=T, num=M+1)
    y = mc_sim(t0=t0, x0=x0, T=T, M=M, N=N, a=a, b=b, sde_method=sde_euler_1, seed=seed)
    plt.plot(t, y)
    plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**
I believe it should be possible to obtain a solution using `numpy.apply_along_axis` and I would still appreciate any suggestions to fix the error mentioned above. However, there is also the possibility to call the function using list comprehension in `mc_sim`:

```
def mc_sim(t0: float, x0: float, T: float, M: int, N: int, a, b, sde_method, seed: int = 0):
    if seed > 0:
        np.random.seed(seed=seed)
    x = np.zeros(shape=(M+1, N))
    x[:, :] = np.array([sde_euler_1(t0=t0, x0=x0, T=T, M=M, a=a, b=b) for i in range(N)]).T
    #x = np.apply_along_axis(sde_method, 0, x, t0=t0, x0=x0, T=T, M=M, a=a, b=b)

    return x
```

This solution is *much* slower than using a vectorized version of the `sde_euler`-simulator - but I was hoping that using `np.apply_along_axis` would be faster than the list comprehension.

Comment: `apply_along` is not faster than a list comprehension.  Don't waste your time on it.

Comment: Your attempt to use `apply` isn't remotely similar to the list comprehension.  `apply` (without the `t0` parameter, will do something like `np.array([sde_euler_1(x[:,i], T, m, a, b) for i in range(x.shape[1]])`.  That is, it passes columns of `x` to `sde_euler_1`, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not type safe, so explicitly defining a type in the function is purely for reference. With this in mind, as the error relates directly to `t0`, try defining it as 0 and not 0.0.

See if that resolves your issue, or provides a different error.

Comment: I've just tried changing from `t0=0.0` to `t0=0` but that did not change the outcome. Also, removing the types in the function declaration also does not have any affect.

Comment: The `type` of the `t0` argument has nothing to do with this error.  There are many reasons for labeling an error as `TypeError`.  `TypeError: sde_euler_1() got multiple values for argument 't0'`.  This has to do with the number of arguments provided to `sde_eulter_1`, not whether any one of them is int or float.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, `apply` is not a performance tool.  But I also suspect you don't understand what it actually does.

To illustrate let's define a simple function.  Note the print to help us see what's happening.

```
def foo(to, a, b):
    print(to,a,b)
    return to*2

In [3]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [10]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x, 'astring',[1,2,3])
[0 4 8] astring [1, 2, 3]
[1 5 9] astring [1, 2, 3]
[ 2  6 10] astring [1, 2, 3]
[ 3  7 11] astring [1, 2, 3]
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
       [16, 18, 20, 22]])
```

The equivalent list comprehension:

```
In [11]: np.array([foo(x[:,i],'astring',[1,2,3]) for i in range(x.shape[1])])
[0 4 8] astring [1, 2, 3]
[1 5 9] astring [1, 2, 3]
[ 2  6 10] astring [1, 2, 3]
[ 3  7 11] astring [1, 2, 3]
Out[11]: 
array([[ 0,  8, 16],
       [ 2, 10, 18],
       [ 4, 12, 20],
       [ 6, 14, 22]])
```

Both are passing `x` to `foo`, one column at a time.

I defined a function with 3 arguments.  `apply` passes the column of `x` as the first, and passes the other **2** as is.

I could have used `np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x, a='astring',b=[1,2,3])`.

But if I try to pass a `to` I get (showing the FULL error message):

```
In [13]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x, to=x, a='astring',b=[1,2,3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 np.apply_along_axis(foo, 0, x, to=x, a='astring',b=[1,2,3])

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in apply_along_axis(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py:379, in apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args, **kwargs)
    375 except StopIteration as e:
    376     raise ValueError(
    377         'Cannot apply_along_axis when any iteration dimensions are 0'
    378     ) from None
--> 379 res = asanyarray(func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs))
    381 # build a buffer for storing evaluations of func1d.
    382 # remove the requested axis, and add the new ones on the end.
    383 # laid out so that each write is contiguous.
    384 # for a tuple index inds, buff[inds] = func1d(inarr_view[inds])
    385 buff = zeros(inarr_view.shape[:-1] + res.shape, res.dtype)

TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'to'
```

The first argument, `to` is supplied by `apply` as part of its iteration; it's not something it passes through.

Also in `np.array([sde_euler_1(t0=t0, x0=x0, T=T, M=M, a=a, b=b) for i in range(N)])`, you aren't using the `i` iteration variable or iterating through anything.  You are just running `sde_euler_1` `N` times.  That's not what `apply` is intended to do.